# Way to add referencing and referenced entities of a specific entity in E-R Diagram MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, toad

Is there any way to add entities that are referencing a specific entity in an E-R Diagram. I have a database containing 400 tables. I want to see a view containing a specific entity and its referencing and referenced entities. Some MySQL clients like toad give a way to add in referenced entities when you drag a specific entity but I could not find a way to add in referencing entities that is those which have that specific entity/table as foreign key in them.

P.S. Managing an E-R diagram containing 400 tables is very very tedious

Answer (score 1):

[SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/diagramming.html) is a free tool that can create database diagrams from the command-line. You can search for tables and columns that you want to include in your diagram using regular expressions. Once you have selected the tables to include, you can also include any number of levels of referenced tables in your diagram. (That is, tables related by foreign keys.) SchemaCrawler can also infer relationships even if foreign keys are not defined, if popular naming conventions are followed.

You meantion that it is tedious to manage E-R diagrams for 400 tables. Yes, it is. I would say, maintain many SchemaCrawler search expressions, which will let you generate many E-R diagrams, for example one for accounts, one for sales, and so on. The added benefit is that these diagrams never go stale - they can be regenerated instantly whenever the schema changes.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler